# ¿Cómo recuperar el número de caracteres de una variable en Jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, python-3.9

**CONTEXTO.** Python 3.9.1 y Jinja2 3.0.1

**OBJETIVO.** Si una variable tipo cadena tiene más de cero caracteres, entonces imprimir un texto.

**PROBLEMA.** No importa si la variable está vacía o tiene más de cero caracteres, siempre encuentro este error: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO.**

Controlador

```
@app.route('/blog')
def blog():
    posts = Blog.getAll()
    return render_template('frontend/blog/index.html', posts=posts)
```

Vista

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <!-- Esta lista imprime correctamente los valores de cada variable -->
    <ul>
        <li>ID: {{ post.id }}</li>
        <li>TITLE: {{ post.title }}</li>
        <li>IMG: {{ post.img }}</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Este condicional es el que marca el error -->
    {% if post.img|d('')|length > 0 %}
        <p>Tiene imagen asignada</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>No tiene imagen asignada</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.
¡Saludos!

Comment: solo basta con hacer `if post.img` ya que si la cadena está vacía eso devuelve `False` y si contiene algo devuelve `True`

Comment: @Christian, juraría que probé eso que dices y no me funcionó. Pero ahora lo hago y funciona correctamente. ¡Muchas gracias, saludos!